# Identify max y for given range in x

Tags: r

Example code:

```
rander <- seq(1, 26000, 45.7)
y <- sample(rander, 50)
x <- seq(1, 50, 1)
df <- cbind(x, y)
df
```

How would I go about identifying the maximum value of y for each 10 units of x?  So I want to find (for x[1-10], max(y)) .

edit:
I want to end up with a dataframe of 5 y maximums for each of the 5 10 unit segment of x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `%/%` to create groups and then use `aggregate`. I've converted your `df` from a `matrix` to a `data.frame` first (and I used `set.seed(1)` when generating my sample data, in case anyone else wants to try to replicate it:

```
df <- data.frame(df)
df$group <- 0:(nrow(df)-1) %/% 10
aggregate(y ~ group, df, max)
#   group       y
# 1     0 24267.7
# 2     1 25318.8
# 3     2 23445.1
# 4     3 24953.2
# 5     4 19834.8
```

Alternatively, you may want to consider `cut`:

```
df$intervals <- cut(df$x, seq(0, max(df$x), 10))
aggregate(y ~ intervals, df, max)
#   intervals       y
# 1    (0,10] 24267.7
# 2   (10,20] 25318.8
# 3   (20,30] 23445.1
# 4   (30,40] 24953.2
# 5   (40,50] 19834.8
```

Comment: I like the output on this one.. im making sure it does what I want.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2795569, let me know if there are any follow-up questions about how either approach is working. They are conceptually different.

Comment: I used the second approach and edited code for preference and to catch special cases.                                       df$intervals <- cut(df$x, seq(-0.0001, (max(df$x)+10), 10))

Comment: There's also an ugly-output way: `with(df,by(y,group,max))`

Comment: @Frank, +1 your comment :)

Comment: Ooops, is there anyway to bring another column of data with aggregate?  googling now... say I wanted to bring the actual value of x with the value of y and the interval

Comment: So after wasting all of your time it turns out what I really want is a vector of row# so that i can just use df[vectrow#,] to get the maximums

Comment: @user2795569, if you learned something, then I would consider it time *not* wasted.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for max value of y for every 10 values of y consecutively then you can just use below.

inner `lapply` creates a list of indices `1:10`, `11:20`, `21:30` and so on. 
outer `lapply` will take these indices and get max value of `y` from those indices

```
lapply(lapply(0:4, function(i) 1:10+ 10*i), function(vec) {max(y[vec])})
```

Comment: I changed the 1 to a .0001 to suit my needs, but very good solution. thanks!